# Can I integrate Orbeon in another application?

Tags: orbeon

I'm mostly interested in being able to load Orbeon into another runtime, in another framework, and use it to generate XHTML output for a form. I have no need for any Orbeon server components. All I need to do is generate XHTML from XForms input. Said output should have all the required .js includes and such to make it work properly.

Can Orbeon do this?

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking Orbeon to act as XSLTForms... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the initial question "can I integrate Orbeon in another application", the answer is of course yes. Orbeon Forms has a few ways of doing this, see in particular [Using the Orbeon Forms XForms Engine with Java Applications](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications).

To the implied question "can I do this without any of the Orbeon server components", the answer is no: Orbeon Forms requires a server component to run. As Alain mentions, in that case you could look at some pure client-side solution like XSLTForms.